# Deleting elements in nested JSON object and flattening it

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, nested-lists

I have a JSON object which looks like something below.

```
[
    {
    "metadata": {
        "Name": "Mike",
        "Age": 28,
        "DOB": "05/19/1992",
        "Profile" : {
            "type" : "standard",
            "payment" : "credit_card"
            },
        "Id" : "xxxyyxx"
        },
     "other" : False,
     "statistics": {
        "clicks": 32,
        "comments": "some text here"
        }
    },
    {
    "metadata": {
        "Name": "Andy",
        "Age": 24,
        "DOB": "10/01/1989",
        "Profile" : {
            "type" : "standard",
            "payment" : "credit_card"
            },
        "Id" : "xxyyyxx"
        },
     "other" : False,
     "statistics": {
        "clicks": 17,
        "comments": "some text here"
        }
    },    ​
]
```

I want to delete elements in this JSON object so it is flattened out, like below, while removing unneccessary items. I want it to look like below.

```
[
    {
    "Id" = "xxxyyxx"
    "clicks": 32
    "comments": "some text here"
    },
    {
    "Id" = "xxyyyxx"
    "clicks": 17
    "comments": "some text here"
    }
]
```

I tried to try deleting objects using pop but I am getting "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration." What is the best way for me to go about that in Python?

Comment: thats invalid JSON.

Comment: @VishalSingh Why is it invalid?

Comment: check here why it is invalid https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I fixed the JSON format. I was more interested in how to go about parsing such a structure.

Comment: @Sue_ka I've added an answer with full working demo, see below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641714/1138192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a valid json, then you can search each object recursively as follows:

```
data = [] # input object
def id_generator(dict_var, attributes):
    for k, v in dict_var.items():
        if k in attributes:
            yield k, v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for id_val in id_generator(v, attributes):
                yield id_val
results = []
search = ("clicks", "Id", "comments")
for row in data: 
    result = {}
    for k, v in id_generator(row, search):
        result[k] = v
    results.append(result)
    
print(results)
```

There are many ways of doing it.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the logic of this and it makes it easier that I don't have to define the names of the dicts explicitly.